# conditionals using switchee

Tags: conditionals, switchee

I was wondering if someone can tell me how to approach this. I have some code that runs through all available entries within a channel and determine if its a match to the pre-determined variable. I can output the matches fine but I want to display a standard form if there is no match.

Here is my code so far

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="dynamic_activity" dynamic="no" author_id="CURRENT_USER"}

    {exp:switchee variable = "{related_activity_id}/{related_adventure_id}" parse="inward"} 
        {case value="{embed:related_activity_id}/{embed:related_adventure_id}"}
            {exp:safecracker 
                channel="dynamic_activity" 
                return="/admin/story/"
                use_live_url="no"
                error_handling=“inline” 
                preserve_checkboxes=“yes” 
                include_jquery="no" 
                author_id="CURRENT_USER"
                entry_id="{entry_id}"
            }
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}">
                <input type="text" name="related_adventure_id" id="related_adventure_id" value="{related_adventure_id}">
                <input type="text" name="related_activity_id" id="related_activity_id" value="{related_activity_id}">
                <input type="text" name="childs_name" id="childs_name" value="{childs_name}">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="button small red">
            {/exp:safecracker}      
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee} 

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here is the form that I want to display if no matches are found.

```
{exp:safecracker 
            channel="dynamic_activity" 
            return="/admin/story/"
            use_live_url="no"
            error_handling=“inline” 
            preserve_checkboxes=“yes” 
            include_jquery="no" 
            author_id="CURRENT_USER"
            author_only="yes"
        }
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Dynamic Content for {embed:related_activity_id}">
            <input type="text" name="related_adventure_id" id="related_adventure_id" value="{embed:related_adventure_id}">
            <input type="text" name="related_activity_id" id="related_activity_id" value="{embed:related_activity_id}">
            <input type="text" name="childs_name" id="childs_name" value="Enter the Childs Name">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button small red">
        {/exp:safecracker}
```

If I use limit="1" then it only displays the first entry  if I check if there is no content that matches then I load the form multiple times for each non matched entry. Any ideas/Help is appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATED: I have also tried this ...

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{related_activity_id}/{related_adventure_id}" parse="inward"}

            {case value="{embed:related_activity_id}/{embed:related_adventure_id}"}
                {exp:safecracker 
                    channel="dynamic_activity" 
                    return="/admin/story/"
                    use_live_url="no"
                    error_handling=“inline” 
                    preserve_checkboxes=“yes” 
                    include_jquery="no" 
                    author_id="CURRENT_USER"
                    entry_id="{entry_id}"
                }
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}">
                    <input type="text" name="related_adventure_id" id="related_adventure_id" value="{related_adventure_id}">
                    <input type="text" name="related_activity_id" id="related_activity_id" value="{related_activity_id}">
                    <input type="text" name="childs_name" id="childs_name" value="{childs_name}">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="button small red">
                {/exp:safecracker}      
            {/case}

            {case default="Yes"}
                {exp:safecracker 
                    channel="dynamic_activity" 
                    return="/admin/story/"
                    use_live_url="no"
                    error_handling=“inline” 
                    preserve_checkboxes=“yes” 
                    include_jquery="no" 
                    author_id="CURRENT_USER"
                    author_only="yes"
                }
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Dynamic Content for {embed:related_activity_id}">
                    <input type="text" name="related_adventure_id" id="related_adventure_id" value="{embed:related_adventure_id}">
                    <input type="text" name="related_activity_id" id="related_activity_id" value="{embed:related_activity_id}">
                    <input type="text" name="childs_name" id="childs_name" value="Enter the Childs Name">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button small red">
                {/exp:safecracker}
            {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stash the output in a variable so you can then show the form if that variable is empty. Something like this should probably work:

```
{!--  ============================================  
FETCH CONTENT
================================================== --}

{exp:stash:set name="content" trim="yes" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="dynamic_activity" dynamic="no" author_id="CURRENT_USER"}

      {exp:switchee variable="{related_activity_id}/{related_adventure_id}" parse="inward"} 
        {case value="{embed:related_activity_id}/{embed:related_adventure_id}"}
            {exp:safecracker 
                channel="dynamic_activity" 
                return="/admin/story/"
                use_live_url="no"
                error_handling=“inline” 
                preserve_checkboxes=“yes” 
                include_jquery="no" 
                author_id="CURRENT_USER"
                entry_id="{entry_id}"
            }
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}">
                <input type="text" name="related_adventure_id" id="related_adventure_id" value="{related_adventure_id}">
                <input type="text" name="related_activity_id" id="related_activity_id" value="{related_activity_id}">
                <input type="text" name="childs_name" id="childs_name" value="{childs_name}">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="button small red">
            {/exp:safecracker}      
        {/case}
      {/exp:switchee} 

   {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{!--  ============================================  
DISPLAY CONTENT
================================================== --}

{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="content"}}
   {exp:stash:get name="content"}
{if:else}
   Fallback content
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a case statement

```
{case default="Yes"}
    Content to show
{/case}
```

Comment: I did try that and it returned the matched results as well as a default form for each unmatched channel entry

Comment: Did you try to move that default above the other case?

Comment: Also what if you moved the: {exp:switchee variable="{related_activity_id}/{related_adventure_id}" parse="inward"} on the outside of the {exp:channel}  Then add the default case outside of {/exp:channel}

Comment: similar results, I think the issue is determining if there are no entries that match within a channel to only display one form. Right now it displays a form for every entry that does not match. I think I am going to try Stash and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend in this particular case you might consider using Croxton's equally impressive ifelse add-on in place of switchee, since it seems like the conditionals you are looking for may be a little outside a purely switch case need. You get all the same benefits of early parsing the outer conditional while only parsing the interior of the matching condition, but with the structure of a conventional if:else kind of approach.  You may find it suits your purpose more closely here.